# Clear Ember MobileDoc-kit Editor Data

Tags: ember.js, mobiledoc-kit

I'm having some trouble with what should be a basic task using the ember-mobile-doc editor: I want to be able to clear the contents of the editor with an action.

with:

```
{{#mobiledoc-editor mobiledoc=document}}...{{#/mobiledoc-editor}
```

I've tried setting `document` to `false`, `null`, without any luck. I've looked through the code on github looking for it, but can't seem to find a path forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I've now come upon this question twice, I need to answer it to save my self the hassle.

jQuery Version:

```
import {run} from '@ember/runloop'
//inside component
   run(() => {
    $('.mobiledoc-editor__editor').empty();
   });
```